# money_format() expects parameter 2 to be double

Tags: php, money-format

I am trying to give the money format 2 variables but I am getting an error message which is this post topic

I did it like

```
$pricetotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
$cartTotal = $pricetotal + $cartTotal;
$minicartTotal = $pricetotal + $cartTotal;
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "en_GB.UTF-8");
$pricetotal = money_format("%n", $pricetotal);
```

I am getting the error message on this codes

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "en_GB.UTF-8");
$_SESSION ['minicart'] = $minicartTotal = money_format("%n", $cartTotal);
$cartTotal = money_format("%n", $cartTotal);
```

also u can see `$minicartTotal` and `$cartTotal` are both doing the same thing... but they i have done it is that i gave it a different variable number but the contents is the same.

What is the best way of doing this to stop the errors

Comment: Well, what does `$cartTotal` contain?

Comment: `$pricetotal` is in the wrong format...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is just to typecast the number like this:

`$_SESSION['minicart'] = $minicartTotal = money_format("%n", (double)$cartTotal);`

But the best way is to make sure that `$price` is a **double** and `$each_item['quantity']` is a **integer** because they are the only unknown variables in your example and if they aren't those types you will get that error.